# How chceck is id is used in other column in same table

Tags: sql, database, mariadb, mariadb-10.3

I'm using MariaDB 10.3 and I have table like:

```
post_id post_content post_user_id post_shared
1       Test1        1             0
2       Test2        2             0
3       Test2        1             2
```

post_shared = 0 means this is original post and is not shared.

I am looking for a way to know if the post has been shared by a particular user (coming from post_user_id). Example output is as follows:

```
post_id isShared                     ( post_user_id 1)
1       0 (false)
2       1 (true)
3       0 (false)
```

I tried a LEFT JOIN to the same table and checked using if condition, but the code is returning me erroneous value.

Thx all for help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a boolean flag using a correlated subquery or `left join`.  If there are no duplicates:

```
select t.*, (ts.post_id is not null) as isShared
from t left join
     ts
     on ts.post_shared = t.post_id and
        ts.post_user_id = 1;
```

As a correlated subquery, this looks like:

```
select t.*,
       (exists (select 1
                from ts
                where ts.post_shared = t.post_id and
                      ts.post_user_id = 1
               )
       ) as isShared
```

Comment: Thx @Gordon Linoff :) This work :) 
I cant understand how subqueris work :)

Answer (score 0):

use corealted subquery

```
select t1.* from table_name t1
where exists( select 1 from table_name t2 where t1.post_user_id=t2.post_user_id
                          and post_shared<>0)
```

Answer (score 0):

With exists:

```
select
  t.post_id,
  case when exists (
      select 1 from tablename
      where post_id <> t.post_id
      and post_shared = t.post_id
    ) then 1 
    else 0
  end isShared                     
from tablename t
```

Answer (score 0):

Using left join

```
SELECT t1.post_id, IF(t2.post_id IS NULL, FALSE, TRUE)
FROM Test as t1
LEFT JOIN Test as t2 ON (t1.post_id = t2.post_shared and t2.post_user_id = 1)
order by t1.post_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution using cases and a text-based [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlXGN.png):

```
SELECT *,
CASE

    WHEN post_shared > 0 THEN 'This story has been shared' 
    ELSE 'This story has not been shared' 

END AS share_status
FROM Test
```

Comment: you dont understend problem ;) Your output is look like: 
post_id(1) not shared,
post_id(2) not shared,
post_id(3) shared.